# Downloadable product of size 0KB

Tags: magento-1.9

Downloadable products are having issue.

After purchasing downloadable product, its links goes to email-id of Buyer.
When a buyer clicks on that link, product is downloading but its size is 0 KB !

No update or edit done in the code. i can download the file directly. it may be max_execute_time setting or any other server setting ?

Comment: Please post more information.

Comment: no update or edit done in the code. i can download the file directly.
it may be max_execute_time setting or any other server setting ?

Answer (score 1):

Without additional details, I'd suggest taking a look at the source file in your Magento admin, and try to download it from there.

It's possible that the file was corrupted and no longer available.

Second, it's possible that the file ownership on the file is not set to allow read access.

Third, check the download one more time - if a file doesn't completely download (i.e. on a slow connection) it will often give a 0 KB file size - the file name is just a placeholder.

I hope this helps...

Comment: 1. Source code is same & no update was done. Same code was working correctly.
2. file ownership of whole magento directories are same.
3. file is downloading correctly when i download the file directly.